# how to change the size of the icon in css?

Tags: nativescript, tabview

how to change the size of the icon, i have downloaded the appropriate size but it's still big, i wanto tre icons in my tab,

her you have my code

```
<TabView androidTabsPosition="bottom" androidSelectedTabHighlightColor="#2f3e4e" selectedTabTextColor="#2f3e4e">

<StackLayout *tabItem="{ title: 'Lektioner' }">
    <page-router-outlet name="Lessons"> </page-router-outlet>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout *tabItem="{ title: 'Opgaver', iconSource: 'res://students' }">
    <page-router-outlet name="Assignments"> </page-router-outlet>
</StackLayout>

<StackLayout *tabItem="{ title: 'Elevliste', iconSource: 'res://students' }">
    <page-router-outlet name="Students"> </page-router-outlet>
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: You cannot explicitly set the size for icon. Which version of tns-core-modules you are using, I believe this issue was addressed in the recent release.

Comment: tns version is 5.2.2

Comment: What is the size of your icon and which drawable folder(s) you have placed it in? What your device screen density?

Comment: when i downloaded i got a file with 5 more files with the appropriat sizes so i moved every icon to the appropriate file.. so i moved icon fra hdpi to hdpi in my project, and mdpi to mdpi so on,  and xxxddpi to xxxhdpi

Comment: my phone is Huawei 10 mate display 2160 x 1080